# CHARTEVENTS Carevue and Metavision

Tags: mimic-iii

I want to find all patients that have measurements for some predefined variables. However items names for carevue and metavision db are different (e.g. Carevue - 'NBP [Systolic], metavision- "Non Invasive Blood Pressure systolic"). Do you have some script to unify these two tables? What strategy should I follow?

Answer (score 1):

I found in mimic github the script [pivoted-vital.sql](https://github.com/MIT-LCP/mimic-code/blob/master/concepts/pivot/pivoted-vital.sql) that solved my problem:

> This query pivots the vital signs for the first 24 hours of a patient's stay
>   Vital signs include heart rate, blood pressure, respiration rate, and temperature

Comment: This query pivots more than the first 24 hours.